# Receive 'Open With' prompt eveytime I open a pdf

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

C# 2008 Express, Winforms.  Using iTextSharp, each time I create a pdf from a template stored on a server I get the ‘Open With’ prompt that asks what program I want to use to open the pdf..which is obviously Acrobat and is the default program to open any pdf.  If I do the same from a pdf that is stored on my local drive I don’t receive the message, nor do I get this when I open any pdf.  Being that I’m going to distribute this program, I don’t want the user to receive this prompt every time.

```
string pdfTemplate = @"\\server\files\Temp\invoice.pdf";
string newFile = @"\\server\files\Temp\completed_invoice";

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.SetField("Name", invoiceName);
pdfFormFields.SetField("Date", invoiceDate);
pdfFormFields.SetField("Address", invoiceAddress);
pdfFormFields.SetField("City", invoiceCity);
pdfFormFields.SetField("State", invoiceState);
pdfFormFields.SetField("Zip", invoiceZip);
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
pdfStamper.Close();
Process.Start(newFile);
```

Comment: Your file above doesn't have a file extension, is that just because its a sample?

Comment: That was the issue....left off the extension.  Yep, I feel pretty foolish now!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string pdfTemplate = @"\\server\files\Temp\invoice.pdf";
string newFile = @"\\server\files\Temp\completed_invoice";

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.SetField("Name", invoiceName);
pdfFormFields.SetField("Date", invoiceDate);
pdfFormFields.SetField("Address", invoiceAddress);
pdfFormFields.SetField("City", invoiceCity);
pdfFormFields.SetField("State", invoiceState);
pdfFormFields.SetField("Zip", invoiceZip);
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
pdfStamper.Close();


ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(newFile); //or any other file name.
start.ErrorDialog = false;
start.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(start);
```

Comment: I receive 'Win32Exception was unhandled' The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application. on line Process.Start(start);

Comment: Change UseShellExecute to true and let me know if that works, please.